# Is it OK to change url scheme for the links to Apache 2 license?

Tags: apache-2.0, license-file, source-code

For an open source project is it OK to modify the original `LICENSE.txt` file from  https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt and also the source file headers to use `https` instead of `http` for the links to the license?

I do not want my users to accidentally follow non-https links.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is not a material change IMHO. You could also contact the Apache Foundation on the legal-discuss list to discuss this change.

But for practical purposes, changing an original license text even if just for a single character is not a great idea. You could instead create your NOTICE with the proper HTTPS url.

As a side and funny note, the bare link to https://apache.org/ is reported as not having a proper SSL certificate in FF. ;)

Comment: that's funny indeed :D. Good that [https://www.apache.org/](https://www.apache.org/) has proper certificate.

Comment: The reason for the HTTPS issue is just that wildcard certs (`*.apache.org`) are not valid for the domain without wildcards (`apache.org`). That's why the cert is not accepted.
Someone should probably report this to the Apache guys.

Comment: with let'sencrypt, acme and certbot not having a valid SSL cert is so 1999!

Comment: FWIW, I contacted the Apache infrastructure team and they are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you get the same result for either URL **right now** it shouldn't be a violation of their license (as determined by following that URL *at this time*).  However, as far as I know the question of having substantive parts of the license contained in a document referenced in this way has never been tested in court, and there are a substantial number who question the applicability.  This is because you are allowing a third party, that is not a party to the license, to change the license terms *at any time, without notice*.  Usually doing that is not allowed.